# What can be done when Finder crashes constantly?

Tags: macos, crash

Finder has started to **crash constantly** such that I can't click the icon in Dock. I **can't click Apple** in top-left corner of the screan (Finder also crash), I **don't have any menubar icons from Apple** like a Time Machine, Spotlight and the system is unstable. Safari crashes but what is confusing Google Chrome, Sparrow and other **3rd party apps works as normal**. Only Apple menubar app that is working is Notification Center.

I tryied to start with **safe mode** but it failed to launch. I have turned **verbose** launch screen on before (it look more cool) so now I can see few error messages on start and after that information that my Mac passes some tests for a brief moment. Login in looks and works normal.

What is possible source of problem and how do I can fix that?

I have MacBook Pro Late 2011 with Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

Comment: What's in your console log?

Comment: Have you tried creating a brand new account and using that?

Comment: Have you tried disabling kernel extensions or launchd services? You can print a list of them with [Consultant's Canary](http://khiltd.com/software/consultants_canary).

Comment: @stuffe when I want to open my Console it crashes :( here is Console crash report - http://pastebin.com/HqcQ14CW

Comment: @lhf I can't enter my system preferences becouse it crashes - crash report http://pastebin.com/3EW9Twsn

Comment: @LauriRanta well... it escalated quickly! FML. Terminal crash report http://pastebin.com/LVrV0TMJ

Answer (score 2):

Only solution was complete [clean reinstall](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/25/how-to-clean-install-os-x-mountain-lion/) of the system.